# Reverse DNS Question and Qmail

Tags: debian, email, reverse-dns

I've setup a mail.example.com, pointed it my server IP. I've also got my provider to setup a Reverse DNS to my server ip to the domain name I setup. AFAIK, what I need now is mail being sent from my mail server on my server IP to have the mail.example.com domain attached to it. How do I do that? Im using qmail.

--Mark

Comment: the current host is www.example.com. Would it be wiser to get the PTR record to point to that instead. Incase its been added to whitelists etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is such mail sent from your mail server? If it's through a script using the sendmail alias (or qmail-inject), you just use

```
sendmail -fuser@mail.example.com
```

This will set the envelope sender (but not the From: field, that's up to you).

Or, you can put "mail.example.com" in /var/qmail/control/defaultdomain, which defaults to the content of /var/qmail/control/me, which should already be mail.example.com. If it's not, change it already.

Comment: cool. Im worred about people who may have added www.example.com to there whitelists. For that reason, Im going to stick with that domain, and get them to change the PTR.